# Calculating the Diffusion coffecients from Trajectory file in ASE

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, python

I plan to study the Diffusion-Coefficient of my simulation outputs, for this, I want to use ASE.
Sadly I am not entirely sure of how to proceed, has anyone done this and if yes, please share your suggestions.

```
class 
ase.md.analysis.DiffusionCoefficient(traj, timestep, atom_indices=None, molecule=False)
```

I also provide the source code,
https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/_modules/ase/md/analysis.html

Thanks in advance.